# encounter ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException when starting corda-webserver.jar which connects to SSL-enabled RPC interface of a node

Tags: corda

Corda Open source v3.2

We tried to enable SSL on RPC interface of a node

node.conf

```
myLegalName="O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
p2pAddress="localhost:10007"
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10008"
    adminAddress="localhost:10048"
    useSsl=true
    ssl {
        certificatesDirectory="./certificates"
        keyStorePassword="cordacadevpass"
        trustStorePassword="trustpass"
    }       
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        password=test
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
        user=user1
    }
]
webAddress="localhost:10009"
useHTTPS=true
```

Ane then we tried to start corda-webserver.jar to connect to SSL-enabled RPC interface of this node, but we encountered following error

```
[INFO ] 2018-10-31T09:36:52,457Z [main] Main.main - Starting as webserver on localhost:10009 {}
[INFO ] 2018-10-31T09:36:52,635Z [main] BasicInfo.logAndMaybePrint - Starting as webserver: localhost:10009 {}
[WARN ] 2018-10-31T09:36:53,254Z [main] internal.config.defaultToOldPath - Config key user has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use username instead {}
[INFO ] 2018-10-31T09:36:53,287Z [main] internal.NodeWebServer.connectLocalRpcAsNodeUser - Connecting to node at localhost:10008 as User(user1, permissions=[ALL]) {}
[INFO ] 2018-10-31T09:37:28,126Z [main] internal.RPCClient.logElapsedTime - Startup took 32973 msec {}
[ERROR] 2018-10-31T09:37:28,126Z [main] internal.NodeWebServer.retryConnectLocalRpc - Cannot start WebServer {}
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException: AMQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:804) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:191) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:123) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:86) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:204) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:196) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:109) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:135) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:120) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.connectLocalRpcAsNodeUser(NodeWebServer.kt:195) ~[corda-webserver-impl-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.retryConnectLocalRpc(NodeWebServer.kt:172) [corda-webserver-impl-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.start(NodeWebServer.kt:45) [corda-webserver-impl-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.WebServer.main(WebServer.kt:64) [corda-webserver-impl-3.2-corda.jar:?]
[ERROR] 2018-10-31T09:37:28,137Z [main] Main.main - Exception during node startup {}
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException: AMQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:804) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:191) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:123) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:86) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:204) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:196) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:109) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:135) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:120) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.connectLocalRpcAsNodeUser(NodeWebServer.kt:195) ~[corda-webserver-impl-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.retryConnectLocalRpc(NodeWebServer.kt:172) ~[corda-webserver-impl-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.start(NodeWebServer.kt:45) ~[corda-webserver-impl-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.WebServer.main(WebServer.kt:64) [corda-webserver-impl-3.2-corda.jar:?]
```

May we know if any missing setting? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Corda 3.x. It will be fixed in Corda 4.